# PHP Session only works when viewing actual index.php?

Tags: php, session

I'm developing a site that uses PHP sessions, but the $_SESSION array is only functioning when the "/index.php" filename is present. "/" and "/index.php" point to the same file, but for some reason the PHP session only works when the "/index.php" is visually present in the URL address. I've searched the web for why this is, and haven't found an answer. Any idea why this is happening?

*NOTE: Sessions work on both "/" and "/index.php" on Localhost, but not on my actual server!

Comment: have you started sessions on all php files???

Comment: Check the session cookie settings, and use a sniffer like Firefox's HTTPFox and/or Firebug's NetTab to see what's going back and forth in the headers.

Comment: @vipin: `/` and `/index.php` would both load the SAME script.

Comment: Do you have any "index.html" file in the same directory as that of "index.php"? If so, then "index.html" will be accessed at first.

Comment: @marc: `/` will point to these specified files `default.html`,`index.html`,`default.php` etc i dont know the order of parsing the files by the server

Comment: @BPRAM no I don't have any index.html files in the directory

Comment: @MarcB I watched what was getting passed using HTTP headers, both "/" and "/index.php" passed the same info. The session is being set, its just not showing up on the "/" file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at the same domain? I had this problem with my website - please note www.example.org is not seen as the same domain as example.org.

Also, please ensure the PHPSESSID cookie is the same on the two URLs. If it is not, it is loading a different session.

Comment: I tried adding the www. before the domain, but it makes no difference, I also checked the PHPSESSID and they are both the same. I made a test session variable on the index.php file itself, and that variable shows up on both the "/" and "/index.php", but the sessions created on a different PHP file only show up only the "/index.php" file?

Comment: Are you certain you directory index is index.php?
I am not sure why it would be otherwise but it is the only logical thing I can think of.

Comment: as am I.
Can you try it on a different server?

Comment: Are you unsetting the session? - unset($_SESSION);
Or maybe re-assigning it? $_SESSION = array();

Comment: no there aren't any unsets, and it isn't being reassigned because it only calls to create the session once. At this point, I'm assuming it has to be because of the (shared) server its on. So I'm going to try a new server, and see if that fixes the problem, thanks for your help!